# Removing attribute when writing file to JSON

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, node.js, api

I have requested data from an API which is returned in JSON format, then written to a JSON file stored on a web server. I am then displaying filtered contents from the stored JSON file to a webpage using Angular.js.

The NodeJS code I am using to write the the API response to a file is the following:

```
var doNotStringify = {
  currentTarget: true,
  delegateTarget: true,
  originalEvent: true,
  target: true,
  toElement: true,
  view : true,
  count : true,
  message : true,
  error : true,
}

tl.employees.all(function(response){
 fs.writeFile(file, JSON.stringify(response, function(key, value) {
    var result = value;
    if(doNotStringify.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        result = undefined;
    }
    return result;
 }, 4));
});
```

This strips out all unneeded elements, apart from 'Data'. I can't strip out Data in the function above as it deletes the contents of the element. So the result is the following JSON file:

```
{
  "Data": [{
    "FirstName": "Test1",
    "LastName": "User",
  }, {
    "FirstName": "user",
    "LastName": "user",
  }, {
    "FirstName": "Ropbert",
    "LastName": "Jones",
  }, {
    "FirstName": "Jim",
    "LastName": "Morrison",
  }]
}
```

When editing out the 'Data' element manually, it works find in HTML/Angular with the following:

```
<td>{{player.firstName}}</td>
```

However, when a new JSON file is written containing the 'Data' element, it breaks and isn't displayed on the web page.

So my Question:

Is there a way to exclude the 'Data' element from writing to a file using fs.writeFile and JSON.stringify?

Or, is there something I can do in Angular get around it?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to strip out the data part, You can just create another element with the contents.In Angular also, I think you can do that with your model. Here is an example(not angular specific):

```
var playerdata = {
  "Data": [{
    "FirstName": "Test1",
    "LastName": "User",
  }, {
    "FirstName": "user",
    "LastName": "user",
  }, {
    "FirstName": "Ropbert",
    "LastName": "Jones",
  }, {
    "FirstName": "Jim",
    "LastName": "Morrison",
  }]
};
playerdata = playerdata["Data"];
console.log(playerdata);

playerdata.forEach(function(player){
console.log(player.FirstName);
})
```